# How would I go about getting this Zefal pump to work with a Schrader valve?

Tags: pump

[image: Zefal pump]

I have a seemingly well-functioning Zefal pump that I'm unable to identify that has a head on that I'm also unable to identify (maybe it's just Presta?).

All my family's bikes use Schrader valves.

Would there be a sensible way to convert the pump to Schrader? As I can't identify the pump I'm struggling to find a replacement aftermarket head.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the thread on the end of the hose is reasonably standard.  Threaded replacement heads are available for many designs.

Comment: Does the head have a dual type like many hand pumps?. Unscrew the retaining cap and pull out the rubber bit. It might be Schraeder size on the other side. There will also be a plastic widget below that to likewise rotated to expose a pin.

Comment: @WarrenBurton as per my comment below ojs' answer, it really didn't seem so... but inspired by your comment I have had another pull at it with some pliers - and yes, it comes out and flips round! Many thanks! (Feel free to put your comment as an answer & I'll accept).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's quite likely the head is dual type switchable.

1. Unscrew the retaining cap.
2. Remove the rubber thing. You might need some gentle encouragement with pliers.
3. Spin it 180. If the other hole is Schrader sized, You're in luck.
4. There will be a plastic widget under the rubber bit. This also needs to be flipped 180 to expose a pin.
5. Put the head back together. Widget, pin up > Rubber Thing, big hole up > Screw Cap.

[image: Schrader valve assembly]

[image: Presta valve pump head assembly]

Not something you want to do if you're working with varied valve types all the time, but as you say your family has one type.

Comment: Thanks. I took the pump head into two shops and neither of them suggested this, so I wonder if this feature of pumps might be less well-known than it should be!

Comment: That’s kind of odd. You’d think a bike shop person should have sold a pump which needed to be flipped for the customer at least once. Even if they ride high end bikes that only use Presta.

Comment: @topomorto Either they wanted to sell you a pump and withheld information, or the people you spoke to are plain incompetent... in both cases, not a good show of professionalism.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any bicycle pump head that is inserted directly to the hose. To install the new head, just cut off the threaded attachment, insert the new head and clamp it in place. It seems that most bicycle pump hoses have same dimensions, and the elasticity of rubber takes care of small differences.

Comment: This seems to be a bigger hose (~11mm ext diameter) compared to my other pump(~8mm)…A couple of random heads I looked at on ebay said they were suitable for 8mmm so perhaps the hose isn't standard...

Comment: Then you may have a problem. The inside diameter is the one that needs to match, but it's difficult to measure with the threaded attachment in place and you probably don't want to cut it before you know the replacement fits.

Comment: Some pumps can be converted from Presta to Schrader by reversing the rubber seal. One thing you could do disassemble the pump head to see if yours is one of them. If it isn't, there are adapters.

Comment: I did try to see if it would come apart as illustrated at http://www.bicyclinglife.com/HowTo/ConvertAPump.htm but it doesn't seem to... I guess it's not worth that much effort; I might take it into a shop and see if they have any ideas.